# Why won't these faces UV unwrap?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to unwrap some new faces after fixing some topology on a model that is already textured (in particular at the edge of the mouth).

For some reason a number of faces just won't seem to unwrap or show up in the UV editor after I select and unwrap them. I've tried pinning vertices around them, messing with seams, and checked the normals, but no luck.

In the viewport, they seem to take the texture. But the faces/verts just aren't showing in the UV editor, so I can't get them in the right place.

The picture shows the gap in the UV where the new faces need to be and on the right are the faces I'm trying to unwrap.

[image]
[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36005)

Comment: those reds dots on the UV Islands vertices means that they are pinned.  This will prevent many operations from succeeding.   Select everything and use Alt-p to clear the pinning.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was that I had 'UV local' view selected, in the UV view options. Not sure what that means yet, but fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. I later found the same problem and it was solved by texture-assigning the faces/vertices in Blender Internal mode then switching back to Cycles.